# How to get the separate parts of a parsed string

Tags: c#

Okay so here is some code:

```
        private void comboBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        renameOld = comboBox4.Text;
        var names = renameOld.Split(new[] { ", " }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string items in names)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(items);
        }

    }
```

Where renameOld is a string like this "Johnson, James" or whatever, right? Anyway, I have it parsed because when I run this, I get the following in the console:

Johnson

James

So obviously, it's working and parsing just like I want it to.

But I want to get each line. I tried doing this thing where I did

Console.WriteLine(items { 0});

I was hoping I'd just get the first part (Johnson), but instead I just got the J.

How can I get each entry set as a separate variable to be used elsewhere in the form?

Comment: Name them? Put them into an array/dictionary? What kind of question is it?

Comment: `items` doesn't contain the items, only the current item. It's the control variable of the loop. If you want to print the first item, drop the loop and use `Console.WriteLine(names[0]);`.

Comment: @Mateusz I don't know how to do that. That's sorta what I'm asking how to do. How to get them from "items" variable into an array, and once I do that, how do I access the stuff within that array?

Comment: `names` **is** already an array - you can get `"Johnson"` using for example `Console.WriteLine(names[0])`.

Comment: @Luaan Thank you, That's exactly what I needed. I'm sorry that I'm such a nub when it comes to coding. This website is very helpful in solving my very basic problems.

Comment: No problem; the question will probably be closed, though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the situation correct but if your situation is:

```
renameOld = "Johnson, James"
```

then names will be a string[] containing ["Johnson"] and ["James"].

So if you want Johnson, just use names[0], if you want james, use names[1] and so on.